# Can anyone explain how to apply custom master page for Access denied page? is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage

I created custom `AccessDeniedNew.aspx` within the layouts folder in 15 hive.

I have applied this customized page in my web application using PowerShell cmdlet as shown below

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutsPage -Identity "AccessDenied" -RelativePath "/_layouts/15/custompages/AccessDeniedNew.aspx" -WebApplication "http:/mywebapplication/".
```

Now I would like to apply my custom master page to custom `AccessDeniedNew.aspx` page which I have created.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a line somewhere in the custom AccessDeniedNew page pointing to a masterpage? Something similar to *MasterPageFile="...."*. Have you already trying changing that one?

Comment: Yup i tried that one it shows error